# Prove existence and uniqueness of roots about a constant d

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm studying for a final exam in the upcoming week and I ran into a problem (Ch 2, question 22) in the book, "An Introduction to Numerical Analysis" by Atkinson, and can't figure out nor find the solution/method for solving it anywhere. This is the question:

Consider the equation

$x = d + hf(x)$

with $d$ a given constant and $f(x)$ continuous $\forall x$. For $h = 0$, a root is $\alpha = d$. Show that for all sufficiently small $h$, this equation has a root $\alpha(h)$. What condition is needed, if any, in order to ensure the uniqueness of the root $\alpha(h)$ in some interval about d?

Answer (score 0):

One has to assume that it is a fixed-pont iteration 
$$
x_+=d+hf(x)?
$$
You mainly need to prove contractivity,
$$
|x_+-y_+|=h|f(x)-f(y)|\overset{?}<|x-y|.
$$
You could also apply the implicit function theorem to $F(h,x)=d-x+hf(x)$.